# Location State Null and Double Rendering in React Application

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working on a React application with React Router v6, and I'm encountering two primary issues that I need help with:

Location State Issue: When I click on an image to navigate to a product detail page, I'm encountering an error that says "location.state is null." This issue occurs when I try to access the state in the ProductDetailPage component using the useLocation hook. I expect to access the state and display product details when navigating to this page.

Double Rendering Issue: Another issue I'm facing is that the console.log output for certain variables, including params, product, and location, is being logged twice. This double rendering behavior is unexpected, and I would like to understand and resolve the root cause of this issue.

Reproduction Steps:

Navigate to the store page.
Click on an image to view the product detail page.
Observe the "location.state is null" error on the product detail page.
After closing the error, notice that the page content is now visible, but the website address remains the same.
Observe that the console.log statements in the ProductDetailPage component are being logged twice.

Expected Behavior:

When I click on an image to view the product detail page, I expect the location.state to be available and not null, allowing me to access the product details.

I expect the console.log statements to be logged only once, as the double rendering behavior is unexpected and could be causing issues.

Additional Information:

I'm using React Router v6 for navigation.
I've included the necessary hooks such as useParams, useLocation, and useNavigate for navigation and state access.
I'm passing state using the Link component when navigating to the product detail page.
Code Snippets:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { CartContext } from "../contexts/CartContext";

const productsArr = [
  {
    title: "Colors",
    price: 100,
    imageUrl: "https://prasadyash2411.github.io/ecom-website/img/Album%201.png",
  }, ...
];

const Music = () => {
  return (
    <section className="text-gray-600 body-font">
      <div className="container px-5 py-24 mx-auto">
        <Products products={productsArr} />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

const Products = ({ products }) => {
  return (
      {products. Map((product) => (
        <Product key={product.title} product={product} />
      ))}
  );
};

const Product = ({ product }) => {
  const { addToCart } = useContext(CartContext);

  return (
    <div className="xl:w-1/4 md:w-1/2 p-4 relative">
      <div className="bg-gray-100 p-6 rounded-lg">
        <Link
          to={{
            pathname: `/store/${product.title}`,
            state: { product },
          }}
        >
          <img
            className="h-40 rounded w-full object-cover object-center mb-6 cursor-pointer"
            src={product.imageUrl}
            alt="content"
          />
        </Link>
        ...//rest of the code
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Music;
```

and

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Switch,
  Navigate,
} from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";
import StorePage from "./pages/Store";
import AboutPage from "./pages/About";
import HomePage from "./pages/Home";
import RootLayout from "./pages/Root";
import { CartProvider } from "./contexts/CartContext";
import ContactUsPage from "./pages/ContactUs";
import ProductDetailPage from "./pages/ProductDetail";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <RootLayout />,
    children: [
      { path: "/home", element: <HomePage /> },
      // navigate in V6 redirect in V5
      { path: "/", element: <Navigate to="/store" replace /> },
      { path: "/store", element: <StorePage />, exact: true },
      { path: "/about", element: <AboutPage /> },
      { path: "/contactus", element: <ContactUsPage /> },
      {
        path: "/store/:productId",
        element: <ProductDetailPage />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </CartProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and

```
// rafce snippet
import React from "react";
import { useParams, useLocation, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const ProductDetailPage = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const location = useLocation();
  const product = location.state.product;
  console.log({ params, product, location });

  return (
    <div>
      ProductDetail: {params.productId}
      <img src={product.imageUrl} alt={product.title} />
      <div>ProductDetail: {params.productId}</div>;
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProductDetailPage;
```

I've provided the relevant code snippets in my previous messages to illustrate how the application is structured.

Request for Help:

I'm seeking assistance in identifying and resolving the issues described above. I'm looking for guidance on how to access the location.state correctly and prevent the double rendering behavior in my React application.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the Link component by the react-router incorrectly:
it should be like this:
`<Link to="new-path" state={{ some: "value" }} />`
Above is the correct way to pass the state to the Link component
you can refer to official page [here](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link).